# I want to load csv file data in SQL but I am getting an error

Tags: database, loaddata

```
LOAD DATA LOW_PRIORITY LOCAL INFILE '/home/worker.csv'
IGNORE INTO TABLE `TEST_db`.`Employee_Info`
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\'' ESCAPED BY '\''
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES (`date`, `Name`, `Gender`, `Mobileno`, `Location`);
```

I'm getting this error :

> 1083 (42000): Field separator argument is not what is expected; check the manual
> Completed execution in 0.22 minutes

CSV file is in the format of

```
'2022-10-31','X','Female','91XXXXX','Argentina'
'2022-10-31','Y','Male','71XXXXXX','India'
'2022-10-31','Z','Female','81XXXXXX','UK'
```

Comment: Please [format your code lines properly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) the way you posted it, it is hard to read.

Comment: Also, I don't understand why you are refering to bash, when there is no bash-code in your question.

Comment: Further, you claim that you get an error message, but the Python statement you posted is unlikely to produce the message. Show the relevant part of your Python code, and point out the very statement which produces the error.

Answer (score 0):

```
LOAD DATA LOW_PRIORITY LOCAL INFILE "/home/worker.csv"
IGNORE INTO TABLE TEST_db.Employee_Info FIELDS TERMINATED BY "," ENCLOSED BY "'"
ESCAPED BY "'" LINES TERMINATED BY "\n" (date, Name, Gender, Mobileno, Location);
```

Comment: Above code worked for me.